# count number of rows per text file using batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop, cmd, md5

I have this batch command that counts the number rows per log/text file. If I have a text file that has 3 or more rows meaning my md5deep verification has a mismatch. The problem is I have multiple folders with CheckMismatch.txt. I am looking for a looping that will CHECK all CheckMismatch.txt and count the rows one by one.

```
IF EXIST C:\BACKUPS\WEBAPP-UAT\WEBAPP\FOLDER1 (md5deep64 -x "C:\BACKUPS\WEBAPP-UAT\WEBAPP\FOLDER1\FOLDER1.md5" -r "C:\BACKUPS\WEBAPP-UAT\WEBAPP\FOLDER1" > C:\BACKUPS\WEBAPP-UAT\WEBAPP\FOLDER1\CheckMismatch.txt
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "cmd=findstr /R /N "^^" C:\BACKUPS\WEBAPP-UAT\WEBAPP\FOLDER1\CheckMismatch.txt | find /C ":""
for /f %%a in ('!cmd!') do set number=%%a
if %number% gtr 2 (echo there is a mismatch in FOLDER1) ELSE (echo FOLDER1 HASHES matched)
)
```

1. Folder1
   CheckMismatch.txt
2. Folder2
   CheckMismatch.txt
3. Folder3
   CheckMismatch.txt
4. Folder4
   CheckMismatch.txt
5. Folder5
   CheckMismatch.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for `FINDSTR` before `FIND`. You can count the rows directly with `FIND` alone. And you can use `FINDSTR` to test if the count is less than or equal to 2. This enables you to use `&&` and `||` instead of `IF`.

If you want to process a fixed list of folders under `"C:\BACKUPS\WEBAPP-UAT\WEBAPP\"`

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "root=C:\BACKUPS\WEBAPP-UAT\WEBAPP"
for %%F in (
  Folder1
  Folder2
  Folder3
  Folder4
  Folder5
) do (
  md5deep64 -x "%root%\%%F\%%F.md5" -r "%root%\%%F" >"%root%\%%F\CheckMismatch.txt"
  type "%root%\%%F\CheckMismatch.txt" | find /c /v "" | findstr /x "0 1 2" && (
    echo There is a mismatch in %%F
  ) || (
    echo %%F hashes matched
  )
)
```

It is more likely that you want to process all folders under `"C:\BACKUPS\WEBAPP-UAT\WEBAPP\"`

```
@echo off
for /d %%F in ("C:\BACKUPS\WEBAPP-UAT\WEBAPP\*") do (
  md5deep64 -x "%%F\%%~nxF.md5" -r "%%F" >"%%F\CheckMismatch.txt"
  type "%%F\CheckMismatch.txt" | find /c /v "" | findstr /x "0 1 2" && (
    echo %%~nxF hashes matched
  ) || (
    echo There is a mismatch in %%~nxF
  )
)
```

If CheckMismatch.txt is just a temporary file that you don't need later on, then you can avoid creation of the file entirely

```
@echo off
for /d %%F in ("C:\BACKUPS\WEBAPP-UAT\WEBAPP\*") do (
  md5deep64 -x "%%F\%%~nxF.md5" -r "%%F" | find /c /v "" | findstr /x "0 1 2" && (
    echo %%~nxF hashes matched
  ) || (
    echo There is a mismatch in %%~nxF
  )
)
```

Comment: What if this is not a fix list. Sometimes **Folder1** is not included in the verifying part but **FOLDER2** onwards are included?

Comment: Thank you so much dbenham. I used the second command. That is what I needed! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There was a delayed expansion problem (using `%number%` in a code block instead of `!number!`)
Tried to format more clearly.

```
@Echo off
SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "Folder=C:\BACKUPS\WEBAPP-UAT\WEBAPP\FOLDER1
IF EXIST "%Folder%" (
    md5deep64 -x "%Folder%\FOLDER1.md5" ^
              -r "%Folder%" > "%Folder%\CheckMismatch.txt"
    set "cmd=findstr /R /N "^^" "%Folder%\CheckMismatch.txt" | find /C ":""
    Set "number=0"
    for /f %%a in ('!cmd!') do set number=%%a

    if !number! gtr 2 (
        echo there is a mismatch in FOLDER1
    ) ELSE (
        echo FOLDER1 HASHES matched)
    )
)
```